# Ansible 2.9 Unexpected failure during module execution error (local connection)

Tags: ansible, local

I have a playbook to update the packages on my local system. Since this is part of the initial system configuration, it is running with local transport. (Ansible is run as: `ansible-playbook -c local -i localhost site.yml`)

The relevant task in the playbook is:

```
- name: "Package Management | Update system"
  dnf:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
  when:
    - config_update_pkgs
    - var_update_pkgs_update_system
```

This task runs and takes a long time, ~15+ minutes usually. When Ansible goes to start the next task, I'm getting this error:

```
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/user.py
<localhost> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-15829904wg505h/tmpqbqnk3tj TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062/AnsiballZ_user.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062/AnsiballZ_user.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'TMPDIR=/var/lib/ansible /usr/libexec/platform-python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062/AnsiballZ_user.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615995245.1999388-218318-225834592190062/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 113, in run
    item_results = self._run_loop(items)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 367, in _run_loop
    res = self._execute(variables=task_vars)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 665, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py", line 51, in run
    if self._task.action in C._ACTION_SETUP:
AttributeError: module 'ansible.constants' has no attribute '_ACTION_SETUP'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}
```

I've been playing with the `persistent_connection` settings in `ansible.cfg` and haven't had much luck yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a run-of-the-mill broken install. Perhaps install ansible into a virtualenv and see if you can reproduce this behavior

Comment: ... and you should report it as a bug to the maintainer of the module. Ansible modules should not trace on system errors.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out what was going on: Ansible itself was getting updated with the rest of the packages. Turns out that Ansible does not like that.

Changing the playbook to:

```
- name: "Package Management | Update system"
  dnf:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
    exclude: ansible
  when:
    - config_update_pkgs
    - var_update_pkgs_update_system
```

stopped Ansible from updating itself and looks like it fixed my problem.

Thanks to @mdaniel for the suggestion that got me looking through what was actually being updated, since I missed it the first time I looked.